# App shutting down when scrolling through table view 'NSRangeException'

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, uitableview, terminate

The twitter feed feature in my app had being working perfectly fine but i tested it again today but whenever i scrolled to the 4th tweet the app would should down. The error i am getting is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (3) beyond bounds (3)'

here is my code

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"
#import "ODRefreshControl.h"


@interface ThirdViewController ()

@end

@implementation ThirdViewController

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)
banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}


@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(void)TableView:(UITableView *)TableView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Can't connect. Please check your internet Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
ODRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[ODRefreshControl alloc] initInScrollView:self.tableView];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(dropViewDidBeginRefreshing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[self fetchTweets];
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
[tempImageView setFrame:self.tableView.frame];

self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;



}


- (void)fetchTweets
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:bikechannel"]];

    NSError* error;

    tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                             options:kNilOptions
                                               error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Tweets %@", tweets);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
});
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return tweets.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSArray *tweetsArray = [tweets valueForKey:@"results"];
NSDictionary *tweet = [tweetsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
//NSString *name = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];

cell.textLabel.text = text;
//cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@", name];

return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"Row %d selected", indexPath.row);
}


- (void)dropViewDidBeginRefreshing:(ODRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self fetchTweets];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
});
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
return 150;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Any idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You are returning to the UITableView as numberOfRows: `tweets count`
Yet, on the cellForRowAtIndexPath, you use as an array:

```
NSArray *tweetsArray = [tweets valueForKey:@"results"];
```

So either you need to set the number of rows to the tweetsArray size, or use the tweets array in the CellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: what is my tweetsArray size?

Comment: I suggest you read a bit about debugging in Xcode. It will help you a lot.

Comment: ok i will, but how would i find this out because i need to fix this really quickly

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you are using tweets as count,

situation where your `tweets` size is 3 but your `tweetsArray` size becomes 4 so your Array goes out of bound,

as are using the `tweetsArray` for populating the rows of the `tableview` so therefore you should return the  count of `tweetsArray` not `tweets`

in your `.h`

```
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSArray *tweetsArray;
```

in your `.m`

```
     - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [tweetArray count]; // this should be number of rows you have data in the array
    }
```

secondly put your this line of code in the `fetchtweets` method after you parse the json data in the tweets

```
NSArray *tweetsArray = [tweets valueForKey:@"results"];
```

Comment: what you get on the console when you do this log statement  `NSLog(@"Tweets %@", tweets);` and tweets is a mutable Array or dictionary?

Comment: when you return the count of tweets , don't try to access it as property with `.`, try to access it like this `return [tweets count];`

Comment: i have never really used nslog or breakpoints, im not very advanced at the whole coding thing. I watched a tutorial on it but im still not able to do or really understand what you said. The tweets is a dictionary i think.

Comment: well i would suggest you to learn about Parsing and how to work with TableViews in ios, there are number of tutorials out there, it is useless to try to solve issues unless you  know how to do the basic stuff and at-least you can read your own code.

Comment: i kind of know how to parse, this code works when i run it and the tweets do display just all of a sudden it stopped working every time when i scroll down, and if i use a different users feed it works fine.

Comment: one problem is that you are setting the number of rows in your tableView equals to tweets, and in your tableView you are adding the rows more than the tweets using the tweetsArray, try to set the no.of.rows of table to tweetsArray, and declare this tweetsArray as a class property, it will help your cause

Comment: i tried that, i replace the existing: 

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return tweets.count;
} with your code but it tells me to put a _ i run it and its just an empty table view.

Comment: because you are populating the tweetsarray in your cellforIndexAtPath, it might be empty when it returns the no.of rows, you should do the parsing before and fill the array and then in cellforIndexAtPath, you could display the values in the table cell. you really should take some time to learn how uitableview work with the help of some tutorial or read about it through some book. it will help a lot believe me. check my answer again, for update

Comment: @user1732646 move this line of code `NSArray *tweetsArray = [tweets valueForKey:@"results"];` to fetchfeeds method as i wroted in my answer, it will solve your problem

Comment: i put it in my method, just below      tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&error];       however it says tweetArray is an unused variable and still nothing appears in the table view.

Comment: it can not be unused because you are suppose to use it in your `cellForRowAtInexPath` with this line of code `NSDictionary *tweet = [tweetsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: yeah i already have that code in the cellForRowAtInexPath like so - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    
         NSLog(@"Tweets %@", tweets);  it still says in the fetchtweets that its an unused variable

Comment: it looks like you don't know exactly what you are doing and , no one can solve your issue like this, you will have to go down to the basics and learn first what you are doing, if you still face problems then you should post here.

Comment: i know i sound like a complete noob  (which i am) and know nothing, but could you please try to help me get it fixed as it is a matter of urgency?

Comment: yes i have been trying to help you but you should try to debug your data with NSlog statements and see what is going wrong and where is going wrong?, and everytime you try something and tell someone you should update your code accordingly in your question so people can know what you are doing.... no one can help like this by what you are saying variable unused. if you need to fix stuff urgently then why not you first learn urgently? what is this urgency where you want to fix something without learning?

Comment: okay if this helps: the app is shutting down on the line: NSDictionary *tweet = [tweetsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: define shutting down? you should check if tweetsArray has data inside it or not? when you parsing the data you should always check by NSLog that what data array contains...